# Как декомпилировать exe написанный на java в исходный код?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, как декомпилировать программу написанную на java, которая находится в формате exe. Видел декомпиляторы, но они работают с jar, class форматами. Пробовал распаковать exe с помощью 7zip, но в ответ получил 25 ошибок. Существует ли аналог .Net Reflector только для java?

Comment: java не компилируется в exe. Возможно, у Вас код, который не на java.

Comment: Зачем вы столько тэгов накидали? Думаете, если поставить тэг `c++` к вопросу про `java` - на него быстрее ответят?

Comment: @KoVadim maven ведь может собрать с плагином экзешник. launch4j вроде. Да, есть отдельная прога. А Есть плагин

Comment: Обычно java и правда не компилируется в exe, но при большом желании можно обернуть. Если точно уверены, что это java, то можно попробовать понять, чем именно собран файл и уже от этого как то вертеться

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, то этот плагин создает exe, который запускает рядом стоящий jar или распаковывает его с ресурсов.. Но сам java компилятор не умеет делать exe.

Comment: На английском stackoverflow есть [такой ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879586/decompile-java-application-packed-with-launch4j). Как написали выше jar можно вытащить из ресурсов.

Comment: @KoVadim не уверен на 100%, но вроде видел какую то утилиту, которая в экхешник заворачивала jvm + jar файл и умела все это запускать. Сам не пробовал, так что возможно не правильно понял описание. Сходу чет не нагуглил

Answer (score 2):

Задача сводится к тому, чтобы достать jar. Для того, чтобы его достать, нужно определить, как он упакован. Если exe-шник является установщиком - надо дать ему установиться и посмотреть нет ли среди файлов, созданных установщиком, jar -ок.

Если нету или если exe-шник не является установщиком, то надо поковыряться в ресурсах exe-шника и поискать jar -ник там. Если и это не поможет, то надо воспользоваться какой нибудь тулзой на подобии PEiD и узнать что за упаковщик. Ну и потом уже гуглить как этот упаковщик расковырять